# JAVA CALCULATOR Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2569)
    at testCalculator.main(testCalculator.java:12)
```

I'm trying to make a working calculator, which reads even decimal numbers, but it doesn't work. At the start it was integer valid only calculator, but within 30 minutes i tried to change it. Sadly my efforts were for nothing, anybody can help me with it? How to improve this calculator, so it can take decimal numbers without errors. Thank you very much for every answer!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        System.out.println("First Number");
        double x = read.nextDouble();
        read.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Second Number");
        double y = read.nextDouble();
        read.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What you want to do? + / * - ");
        String z = read.nextLine();

        switch(z){
            case "+":
                System.out.println(x + y);
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.println(x - y);
                break;

            case "*":
                System.out.println(x * y);
                break;

            case "/":
                System.out.println (x / y);
                break;
            default:
               System.out.println("bruh");
               break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I run your code and I don't get a problem.  I entered two decimal numbers and an operation three times in a row, and it worked fine for me.  Strange that you're getting that error.  How are you running your code...what IDE, etc. ?

Comment: Hello @CryptoFool! I'm already using "IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.2" (I put the whole name of the current version from my desktop). If it's working for you, then I just don't know what is going on. Is it possible that the number of classes that I created in my src on my Project is too big?

Comment: I'm running IntelliJ as well.  The number of classes shouldn't matter, especially once your code is running and prompting you for numbers.  That's really weird.  I've never seen that particular error before from Scanner.

Comment: So it's not a common thing, as I understand. Maybe I'll try to create a new project, and will do copy + paste this code. I'll tell you in a minute if it worked.

Comment: Have you tried running outside of IntelliJ, like at the command line?

Comment: I didn't try it. I'm not even sure how to run it at the command line. I'm new to programming stuff. Btw. I just created a new project and I ran this program, but it still has the same problem.



-------------------

First Number
21.15
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2569)
 at testCalculator.main(testCalculator.java:9)

Process finished with exit code 1

-------

Comment: InputMismatchException shows that you put in the wrong input, like a String: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

Comment: Also add this line in main and add to post to rule out a locale issue: `System.out.println(java.util.Locale.getDefault());`.

Comment: @ LeoDog896 I don't know, I just simply wrote "21.15" as a random decimal number, just to show you the error that I got. I read my code a few times, but I think that everything is correct, the first guy @CryptoFool. This code worked for him, but somehow doesn't work for me.
@ Gardener I added this line of code and the output is "pl_PL"

Comment: Try 21,15 - decimal separator in poland locale (pl_PL) should be "comma".  ( https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/pl-PL/index.html )

Comment: Oh my.. it worked, so I just needed to put a comma instead of a dot, dang. Why I didn't think about it before, ugh. 
Thank you all guys for helping me with this little problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the locale info (pl_PL) the decimal separator is a comma, e.g. 21,15.

To discover such things add the line

```
System.out.println(java.util.Locale.getDefault());
```

Use the supported locales to [look it up](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html):

```
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html
```

And get further info on the locale:

https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/pl-PL/index.html

and reference the "Decimal separator" value: `,`.